# How to get list name and slice name with pipe and purrr

Tags: r, ggplot2, pipe, purrr

I wonder how to get the list name or group name as a flag when using pipe operation with purrr. for example: I want to use a dynameic parameter of each list name pass to the ggsave function.

```
require(purrr)
require(ggplot2)
lst=list(a1=data.frame(x=1:10,y=2:11),a2=data.frame(x=1:10,y=-1*2:11))
df=rbind(transform(lst[[1]],id="a1"),transform(lst[[2]],id="a2"))
lst %>% map(~ggsave(plot=qplot(data=.,x="x",y="y",geom="line"),file=paste(listname(.),".png")))
df %>% slice_rows("id") %>%
  by_slice(~ggsave(plot=qplot(data=.,x="x",y="y",geom="line"),file=paste("slicename(.)",".png")))
```

the slicename(.) should be something like unique(.[["id"]]), but it does not work when using slice_rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`listname` and `slicename` aren't functions in `purrr` and `names` doesn't seem to return the list element name when used with `purrr` functions.  Also, you probably want to use the `walk` family of functions rather than `map` or `by_slice` since you're calling the function for its side effects, not for the returned object.

So as a bit of workaround, you might try

```
   lst=list(a1=data.frame(x=1:10,y=2:11),a2=data.frame(x=1:10,y=-1*2:11))

   list(lst, names(lst)) %>% 
        pwalk( ~ ggsave(plot=qplot(data=.x,x=x,y=y,geom="line"),filename=paste(.y,".png")) )
```

**Added**

If you're starting with a data frame, you could use

```
df %>% split(.$id) %>% 
       list( names(.)) %>% 
       pwalk( ~ ggsave(plot=qplot(data=.x, x=x, y=y, geom="line"), filename=paste(.y,".png")))
```

Comment: Thanks!
So is it the best way for a grouped data.frame:

`lst=list(a1=data.frame(x=1:10,y=2:11),a2=data.frame(x=1:10,y=-1*2:11))
df=rbind(transform(lst[[1]],id="a1"),transform(lst[[2]],id="a2"))
df %>% split(.[["id"]]) %>% 
  list(.,as.character(unique(df[["id"]]))) %>%
  pwalk( ~ ggsave(plot=qplot(data=.x,x=x,y=y,geom="line"),filename=paste(.y,".png")))`

Comment: if the unique(df[["id"]]) is a factor rather than a character class, the result is different (1.png, 2.png), maybe this is a bug.

Answer (score 6):

It is worth mentioning that using `purrr::walk2` one can avoid creating a new list with `lst` and `names(lst)` elements:

```
lst=list(a1=data.frame(x=1:10,y=2:11),a2=data.frame(x=1:10,y=-1*2:11))

purrr::walk2(
  lst,
  names(lst),
  ~ ggsave(plot=qplot(data=.x,x=x,y=y,geom="line"),filename=paste(.y,".png"))
)
```

*Updated 2017-08-30*: A new family of "indexed" map functions has been [introduced](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/blob/master/NEWS.md) in `purrr` 0.2.3 that provide a short-hand for `walk2(lst, names(lst))`:

```
lst=list(a1=data.frame(x=1:10,y=2:11),a2=data.frame(x=1:10,y=-1*2:11))

purrr::iwalk(
  lst,
  ~ ggsave(plot=qplot(data=.x,x=x,y=y,geom="line"),filename=paste(.y,".png"))
)
```