# getting named lists from purrr::map like in plyr::ldply

Tags: r, plyr, tidyverse

How can I get a named list back from `purrr::map` the same way I could do it with `plyr::dlply`? I am providing a reprex here. As can be seen, plyr::ldply returns a named list while `purrr::map` doesn't. I also checked out a similar question from 2 years ago ([How to get list name and slice name with pipe and purrr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834647/how-to-get-list-name-and-slice-name-with-pipe-and-purrr)), but that wasn't that helpful because there `purrr::map` is not being used on a list column inside a dataframe and that's what I want to do.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)

# creating a list of plots with purrr
plotlist_purrr <- iris %>%
  dplyr::group_by(.data = ., Species) %>%
  tidyr::nest(data = .) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    .data = .,
    plots = data %>% purrr::map(
      .x = .,
      .f = ~ ggplot2::ggplot(
        data = .,
        mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)
      ) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
    )
  )

# see the names of the plots
names(plotlist_purrr$plots)
#> NULL

# creating a list of plots with plyr
plotlist_plyr <- plyr::dlply(
  .data = iris,
  .variables = .(Species),
  .fun = function(data)
    ggplot2::ggplot(
      data = data,
      mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)
    ) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
)

# see the names of the plots
names(plotlist_plyr)
#> [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Created on 2018-03-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

I am trying to move away from `plyr` and completely depend on `tidyverse` in my scripts but some of the things I could do with `plyr` I am still trying to figure out how to them with `purrr` and this is one of them.

Comment: Try `my_way <- iris %>%
  split(.$Species) %>%
  map(~ggplot(.,mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width))
       + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")); 
names(my_way)`

Comment: @Jimbou Nice! But I would like to do this within a dataframe, if possible. I'll wait to see if other people come with some alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `purrr::set_names(Species)` before doing `map`

```r
library(plyr)
library(tidyverse)

# creating a list of plots with purrr
plotlist_purrr <- iris %>%
  dplyr::group_by(.data = ., Species) %>%
  tidyr::nest(data = .) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    .data = .,
    plots = data %>% 

      purrr::set_names(Species) %>%

      purrr::map(
      .x = .,
      .f = ~ ggplot2::ggplot(
        data = .,
        mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)
      ) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
    )
  )

# see the names of the plots
names(plotlist_purrr$plots)

#> [1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

Created on 2018-03-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
my_way <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(plots= data %>%  
                  map(~ggplot(., aes(x= Sepal.Length, y= Sepal.Width)) +
                        geom_point() + 
                        geom_smooth(method= "lm"))) %>% 
  mutate(plots= set_names(plots, Species))

my_way
# A tibble: 3 x 3
Species      data              plots   
<fct>        <list>            <list>  
1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]> <S3: gg>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]> <S3: gg>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]> <S3: gg>

names(my_way$plots)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```